# Anti imagration

Tags: customs-and-immigration

she says and i have seen visa, pasport and now she is  asking for 1.000 to prove she can support her self while she is here in the united states . And she says that she has every thing but does not have the funds to continue

Comment: who is asking what ?

Comment: Scam scam scam scam. Scam scam. Scam.